# php html email missing variable data

Tags: php, email, send

I am sending a php email with script inside an html body. When the message is sent the echo output shown in the script below displays to the screen nicely, but it is missing from the email body received.

How can I include this section in my email?

This is the code I am using

```
// Put your HTML here
$message = file_get_contents('.message_update.html');
echo $message;
$Date = date('d/m/Y');
$count = 0;

$new_dir = str_replace('_', ' ', $dir);
echo "<font color='blue'>";
echo "The folder name at the website message page is: ", 
$new_dir."<br /></font>";
$message .= 'The folder name at the website message page is: ", 
$new_dir."<br /></font>';
$comparison = array_diff($list2, $list1);

foreach ($comparison as $line) {
echo "Date Update: ", $Date, " : To listen to the ", ++$count, "
```

message click the picture
here ";

```
echo '<a href="' . $folder_path, $line . '"><img align="top" 
width="100" height="20"  text-    
align: center; 
src="https://nerjabible.com/images/audio_player1.png" /></a>';
echo ", The ", $count, " message name is entitled:    ", $line. " 
<br />";
}

$message = file_get_contents('.message_update1.html');
echo $message;

// Mail it`
```

`
The output of the first html file .message_update.html is included in top of the email received.
Then the variables from the script are missing
The output of the second .message_update1.html is included at the bottom of the email received.

How can I wrap this section

```
$new_dir = str_replace('_', ' ', $dir);
echo "<font color='blue'>";
echo "The folder name at the website message page is: ", 
$new_dir."<br /></font>";
$message .= 'The folder name at the website message page is: ", 
$new_dir."<br /></font>';
$comparison = array_diff($list2, $list1);

foreach ($comparison as $line) {
echo "Date Update: ", $Date, " : To listen to the ", ++$count, " 
message click the picture    
here ";

echo '<a href="' . $folder_path, $line . '"><img align="top" 
width="100" height="20"  text-    
align: center; 
src="https://nerjabible.com/images/audio_player1.png" /></a>';
echo ", The ", $count, " message name is entitled:    ", $line. " 
<br />";
}
```

and include it in the $message variable?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [Output Control Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes but how do you write something like $message = {missing section};?

Comment: Currently you `echo` it to the output of your page. You could, instead, store it in a variable, and use that in your `$message`. So, instead of `echo 'hello!';` you do: `$hello = 'hello!';`, or `$hello .= 'hello!';`, and then `$message = "I am saying $hello.";`.

Comment: But how do I concatenate all the lines with mixed code. i.e "The folder name at the website message page is: ", $new_dir."<br /></font>"; would not work on your example with $message = "I am saying $hello.";.

Comment: See: [String Concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.other) and [String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: What about adding the php variable in the html documentation, I tried but not sure of the syntax, <echo ?php $line ?> does not work